# Hi, I'm trying to replicate an event listener with different elements on my page, pairing different elements with different keys

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);

function logKey(e) {
  
  if(e.code == 'KeyB') {
    var tag = document.querySelector('.batman');
    tag.classList.toggle('active');
  }
}
```

```css
body {display:flex; flex-flow:row wrap; align-items:center; justify-content:center; background:#333 url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1475862013929-0af29a1197f4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2534&q=80) fixed 50% 50%/ cover; }
.holo {margin:0 10px 20px 10px; xwidth:300px; xheight:200px; border:5px solid rgba(0,100,200,0.5); border-radius:20px;  text-align:center; color:rgba(0,100,200,0.9); background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); transform:scale(1.0);}

.holo:hover, .holo.active {background:rgba(30,30,30,0.8); transition-duration:0.5s; transform:scale(1.1);}


.holo h1 {font:bold 30px Arial; text-transform:uppercase;}
.holo img {width:100%; width:300px; margin:10px; border-radius:20px;}
```

```html
<div class="holo batman active">
  <h1>Batman</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509347528160-9a9e33742cdb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
</div>

<div class="holo">
  <h1>Spiderman</h1>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521714161819-15534968fc5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
</div>
<div class="holo">
  <h1>Iron Man</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509817445409-e2057fd6feac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
  
</div>

<div class="holo">
  <h1>Thor</h1>
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495044245703-b07f266e47b4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
  
</div>

<div class="holo">
  <h1>Spiderman 2</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505925456693-124134d66749?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2550&q=80">
  
</div>
<div class="holo">
  <h1>The Dark Knight</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519740296995-10d3d8267019?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
  
</div>
<div class="holo">
  <h1>Avengers</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1471877325906-aee7c2240b5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
  
</div>

<div class="holo">
  <h1>WonderWoman</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517242296655-0a451dd85b30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
  
</div>
<div class="holo">
  <h1>Spiderman 3</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534375971785-5c1826f739d8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
  
</div>
```

I want to use an event listener to get every element on the page to respond to a keypush - however, I'm having problems replicating the Javascript code for each element, it just won't work.

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');

document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);

function logKey(e) {

  if(e.code == 'KeyB') {
    var tag = document.querySelector('.batman');
    tag.classList.toggle('active');
  }
}
```

I want to use a different key - say 'KeyA' for a different element - say '.spiderman'. I've tried replicating the code above with these replacements, but this hasn't worked.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: [Without a complete example no one could possibly say.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  I did try this in the console and it works just fine: `document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { console.log(e.code) })`.  Also, `const input` is doing absolutely nothing here.  Hope you can figure it out.

Comment: how do I add a complete example? here's a link to my CodePen by the way, which has all the code: https://codepen.io/coinscrum/pen/NmJYGO

Comment: I've now added a snippet - hopefully this adds more clarity?

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot to assign each separate `div` a classname. I added the names for all of them, but only tied in batman and spiderman (`b` and `s` keys). Try it out, and you can easily add the rest of them.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);

function logKey(e) {
  if(e.code == 'KeyB') {
    var tag = document.querySelector('.batman');
    tag.classList.toggle('active');
    
    console.log('B clicked')
  }
  
  if (e.code == 'KeyS') {
    var tag = document.querySelector('.spiderman');
    tag.classList.toggle('active');
  
    console.log('S clicked')
  }
}
```

```css
body {display:flex; flex-flow:row wrap; align-items:center; justify-content:center; background:#333 url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1475862013929-0af29a1197f4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2534&q=80) fixed 50% 50%/ cover; }
.holo {margin:0 10px 20px 10px; xwidth:300px; xheight:200px; border:5px solid rgba(0,100,200,0.5); border-radius:20px;  text-align:center; color:rgba(0,100,200,0.9); background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); transform:scale(1.0);}

.holo:hover, .holo.active {background:rgba(30,30,30,0.8); transition-duration:0.5s; transform:scale(1.1);}


.holo h1 {font:bold 30px Arial; text-transform:uppercase;}
.holo img {width:100%; width:300px; margin:10px; border-radius:20px;}
```

```html
<div class="holo batman">
  <h1>Batman</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509347528160-9a9e33742cdb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
</div>

<div class="holo spiderman">
  <h1>Spiderman</h1>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521714161819-15534968fc5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
</div>
<div class="holo ironman">
  <h1>Iron Man</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509817445409-e2057fd6feac?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
  
</div>

<div class="holo thor">
  <h1>Thor</h1>
   <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495044245703-b07f266e47b4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
  
</div>

<div class="holo spiderman2">
  <h1>Spiderman 2</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505925456693-124134d66749?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2550&q=80">
  
</div>
<div class="holo darkknight">
  <h1>The Dark Knight</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519740296995-10d3d8267019?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
  
</div>
<div class="holo avengers">
  <h1>Avengers</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1471877325906-aee7c2240b5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
  
</div>

<div class="holo wonderwoman">
  <h1>WonderWoman</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517242296655-0a451dd85b30?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
  
</div>
<div class="holo spiderman3">
  <h1>Spiderman 3</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534375971785-5c1826f739d8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much! How do you ensure that multiple elements respond when multiple keys are pressed - say for example I wanted batman/thor/spiderman to respond at the same time when pressing the relevant keys? For now, only two elements work together - how can I ensure that pressing 3 keys will cause their relevant elements to respond?